# Fork function involving for loop

Tags: c, linux, fork

I'm having a great deal of pain trying to figure this issues out. So, what I'm trying to do is create 3 child processes stemming from one parent process. I have figured that out but the problem is my program exits when it get to the third child leaving it orphaned(I think). This is my code for the first generation of processes:

```
int i = 0;
int corpse;
int status;
pid_t child;
about("Dad");
printf("Now ..  Forking !!\n");

about("Dad");
for(i=0; i<3; i++){
child = fork();

  if (child == 0){

    about ("son");
    break;

  }else if (child < 0){

    perror ("Unable to fork!");
    break;
  }

}

void about(char * msg)
{
 pid_t me;
 pid_t old;

 me = getpid();
 old = getppid();

 printf("[%s] Hi, my pid is %d and I come from %d.\n", msg, me, old);
}
while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0){
    printf("Child process PID=%d terminates\n", corpse);
}
```

Now my output looks like:

```
[Dad] Hi, my pid is 2940 and I come from 2883.
Now ..  Forking !!
[Dad] Hi, my pid is 2940 and I come from 2883.
[son] Hi, my pid is 2941 and I come from 2940.
[son] Hi, my pid is 2942 and I come from 2940.
Child process PID=2941 terminates
Child process PID=2942 terminates
[son] Hi, my pid is 2943 and I come from 2940.
Child process PID=2943 terminates
```

Comment: Show your *actual code*. It makes no sense to show code with a `continue` statement but no loops.

Comment: You don't have a third child.  You only forked once.

Comment: I added the for loop, sorry I copied the wrong thing.

Comment: You don't call `fork` *inside* your loop. If you do, please edit your question to show the real code. Don't forget to test the result of every call to `fork` (three cases: positive, zero, negative)

Comment: Okay, I changed the question with all the suggestions. Could I leave out the positive case and put that out side of the for loop? So, I would call about('Dad') by itself before the for loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Note that the output starts `'[dad] hi, …'` but the code shows `"Dad"` and `"Hi, …"` (and `"now forking..."` vs `"Now ..  Forking !!"`.  That means we know the output doesn't come from the program you show.  Please, be sensible.  Use copy'n'paste to copy the exact code you compile and run, and the output you get from exactly the same code.  Don't do 'approximately the same code'. See how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Incidentally, the example output shows three child processes (1235, 1236, and 1237).  To make the behaviour more nearly determinate, you should have a loop waiting for the children to die: `int corpse; int status; while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0) printf("PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);`.

Comment: I updated the question. I moved the parent process before the for loop and the output works just fine. Is this a good idea or will this eventually fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I could get it right, you are worried about the child process to become Orphan, then you may use **wait or waitpid**. By using any of these, parent process can wait for the child process to terminate.
For more help use "man wait".